# What exactly is a reference in Java?

Tags: java, reference

What exactly is a reference in Java? Is it a memory address? Is a Java reference the equivalent of a dereferenced C++ pointer?

In other words, given the following:

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();

o1 == o2
```

Is the above comparison the equivalent of comparing two pointers in C++?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`o1 == o2` is pretty much equivalent to comparing two pointers in C/C++, yes.

But there are a two main differences between references in Java and pointers in C/C++ that are quite important:

- Java references can't do pointer arithmetic: you can't "add 3" to a reference, you can *only* let it point to another (known) object
- Java references are stongly typed: you can't "reinterpret" what lies on the other end of a reference *unless* you reinterpret it as a type that *that object actually is*.

Also a short note about the word "reference": C++ has references that act quite differently from both pointers in C and references in Java (but I don't know enough about C++ to tell you the specifics).

For a thorough discussion of this, see [this related question on programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer).

Comment: A heads up about coming feature 10 years later: As part of the introduction of value object to Java in [Project Valhalla](https://openjdk.org/projects/valhalla/) `==` will compare user defined value objects by [comparing all their respective fields](https://github.com/openjdk/valhalla-docs/blob/main/site/design-notes/state-of-valhalla/02-object-model.md#identity-sensitive-operations). `==` will hence not always be a pointer comparison any more.

Comment: @Lii: true, this answer will need to be updated eventually, but I'd prefer not to confuse this very fundamental question with that until Valhalla/JEP 401 is at least a preview feature in regular GA builds (before that we don't really know what it'll look like or even if it comes out at all).

Answer (score 5):

> What exactly is a reference in Java?

It is an index of an object.  It can be thought of as like a pointer but it differs in the fact that it

- can change at any time.
- does not always have a direct relationship with memory addresses.
- is usually 32-bit in a 64-bit JVM.
- you can't re-interprete what the reference refers to. You can only change the type of the reference itself.

> Is the above comparison the equivalent of comparing two pointers in C++?

Yes.

---

On Compresses Oops which allows a 64-bit JVM to sue 32-bit references.

[Java HotSpot™ Virtual Machine Performance Enhancements - Compressed Oops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop)

[Compressed oops in the Hotspot JVM](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)

[IBM V6 - More effective heap usage using compressed references](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.user.lnx.60/user/garbage_compressed_refs.html)

Comment: I have added some links on compressed OOPs or references.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a reference is basically the same thing as a pointer. By the way, if you call a method  on a null reference, you get... a NullPointerException.

Note that it doesn't have to be a memory address, though. A given object can be stored elsewhere during a program execution, and still keep the same reference. But you don't need to care, as pointer arithmetic doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is a "pointer" to a memory address in Java, even though Java eleminates direct manipulation of pointers, unlike C++. Objects in Java are never passed to methods or returned by methods, it is always a reference that is being passed.