# Is the performance of ArrayList.get() affected when multiple datatypes are stored in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was looking at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/10118965) answer to a popular Java question. I understand that the benefit of an ArrayList of X datatype is that `get(5)` is supposed to be instantaneous because finding the 5th element is just a matter of traveling 5 units of a datatype forward in the array before you ever have to actually access any data. LinkedList requires accessing each nodes data to find where the next node will be, and continuing this process until the 5th step has been reached. Hence the reason why ArrayList is better than LinkedList when it comes to retrieving data.

However, what if the datatype is variable in size? What if I declare an ArrayList with an `Object` type parameter, so that I can add both a char (1 byte) and an int (4 bytes) in the ArrayList? How would the ArrayList know where the next element is, since it can't just travel `(sizeOfDatatype * steps)` forward until it reaches its goal? Would it store data to the largest datatype available, such as with alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414920/why-primitive-datatypes-are-not-allowd-in-java-util-arraylist) question. It sort of answers my question, but only partway. This answer is to provide a complete answer to my question.

~

The question is built on the faulty premise that ArrayList stores the value of an object (or the value of a primitive data type). While it may not look it, ArrayLists don't store values, they store object references. Notice how you can `add(int i)` or `add(char c)`, but you can't declare an ArrayList with an int as the type parameter? The reason is because ArrayLists are storing the object reference, [essentially a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12565077/10118965), and traversing these pointers (all of which have the same size since they are all pointers). Primitive data types, such as int, are not reference types, they are primitive types, and thus not allowed to be type parameters. You are still allowed to use int as a parameter for `add()` because of [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), but that's only for convenience.

So no, performance of `get()` is untouched when storing multiple data types in an ArrayList because you are only storing references to Objects.

Comment: As a side note, this will likely change when generics support primitive and value types in the future. You can read about the JEP [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218).

Comment: Thank you @Logan . I could sort of follow along. The basic gist is that there will be some change in the future that will mean the type parameter (the generic) doesn't have to start with Object, and autobox to where you need it to, it can be the primitive from the getgo. Am I getting that right?

Comment: That’s correct. You will be able to use a `List<int>` instead of `List<Integer>`.

Comment: What exactly is the question aimed at, if you can answer it immediately :)?
Also on a side-note: The int in get(int) is an index position in the list, so there is no autoboxing required, if you pass a primitive int. However, if you pass a  wrapped Integer, it will be automatically unboxed.

Comment: Neat. And I'm still trying to figure out what value types are, but I understand that they're something that stores value, so when you pass it through as a parameter, you are passing through the values?

Comment: @TreffnonX Good call. I changed to add (wrote get because brainfart). To answer your question, if you're talking about the comment I made, that was just to keep up. I've talked with some industry heads and what little I thought I knew, I really didn't know, so I want to keep up with everything I can come across. If you're talking about the original post, same reason, but I actually am interested in optimization and how that would take place in a higher level language like Java. I wanted to get a good idea of how the ArrayList worked in order to properly optimize it.

Comment: @TreffnonX Or am I misunderstanding you? Are you asking why I answered my question immediately? Truthfully, I started writing this question hours ago, found the answer 30 minutes ago, and only decided to post it because I felt like the answer was a bit tricky for me, so it might be a bit tricky for others who were struggling with the same question too.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration that you can only declare an `ArrayList` that takes some sort of `Object` (or a boxed primitive) *and* you call `get` *by index* - the time to retrieve an element is `O(1)` meaning it is constant - pretty much obvious when retrieving by index.

ArrayList also implements `RandomAccess` interface to specifically denote that fast retrieval.