# If (x == "0") issue

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement

I have a string variable where the value is often "0" it is also often not "0".

Whenever I update this value, it needs to be parsed.
I know that this string, when it is zero it cannot be parsed.

However I do not understand why the if statement comparing two strings isn't working, there must be some logic behind it that I do not understand and I would appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm missing.

I have solved the issue by using `.equals("0")`, but I have no idea why this method works and the other one doesn't. Thank you in advance.

```js
if (x == "0") {
  integer = 0;
} else {
  integer = Integer.parseInt(x);
}
```

Comment: The way you have it now is a reference comparison, but you want value comparison.

Comment: @SPlatten Java != JavaScript

Comment: Because "==" compares [object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565037/what-exactly-is-a-reference-in-java), not string values.  You can read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have solved the issue by using .equals("0"), but I have no idea why this method works and the other one doesn't.

`==` in Java compares reference (similar to "pointer" in C), `String.equals()` is an overriden method that will compare the content.

Comment: So in what case would i need to use "==" operator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .equals() when comparing strings:

```
x.equals("0")
```

To avoid problems with x being null you can do the following:

```
"0".equals(x) // or Objects.equals(x, "0") as suggested by @knittl
```

This will work correctly:

```
// x == "0" is reference comparison
// this is value comparison
if (x.equals("0")) {
  integer = 0;
} else {
  integer = Integer.parseInt(x);
}
```

Comment: And to avoid problems with x being null, make it `"0".equals(x)` or `Objects.equals(x, "0")`

Comment: Im i right in thinking that the "0" before the number is a default value? if the .equals cannot return a value due to X being null, it will return "0"?

Comment: @adjawsdaw No, "0" is a String object. We call the member function .equals on it to compare it to the value inside x. If the values match .equals returns true; if they don't match .equals returns false. I hope that this makes sense. Please let me know if I can clarify this further.